# Subspace $spanE$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $E\subseteq V$.

How to show that span($E$)$=\bigcap\ \{U\ |\ U $$\ \ $is a subspace of $V$ and $U$ contains $E \ \}?$

I know the theorem ; If $\ V$ is a vector space and  $E\subseteq V$, then span($E$) is a subspace of $V$

Could anyone help me?

Comment: To show set equality $A=B$ show $A\subseteq B$ and $ A \supseteq B$. One direction should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: Tip: Format text in MathJax using ```\text{}```. $\text{span}(E)$ is far better than $spanE$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U$ contains $E$, and $U$ is subespace of $V$, then $U$ contains $\text{span} (E)$: If $x \in  \text{span} (E)$, then $x = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i x_i$, with $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in E$, and $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ scalars. But, since $U$ is subespace and $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in U$, the linear combination $x = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i x_i$ belongs to $U$. Then $U \supset \text{span} (E)$, and $\text{span} (E) \subset \bigcap\ \{U\ |\ U $$\ \ $is a subspace of $V$ and $U$ contains $E \ \}$. What we did means that $\text{span} (E)$ is the small subespace that contains $E$.

In the other hand, then $\text{span} (E) $ is also a subespace of $V$, and contains $E$. Soon it is one of the subspaces that is part of the intersection, it follows that $\text{span} (E) \supset \bigcap\ \{U\ |\ U $$\ \ $is a subspace of $V$ and $U$ contains $E \ \}$.